# What is the difference between 这类 and 这种?

Tags: word-choice

As far as I know they both mean this kind (of).
Is the latter more versatile or less?
Does that have any influence on the choice of word?

Is it an etymological feature that provides or shows a differentiation, if such a differentiation is existent ?

Comment: ghits (8th August 2017): 
这种  610M
这类  38M

Comment: what is the difference between "this kind of" and "this sort of" ("this type of")?

Comment: in English, diction is going to play a huge role..something that Chinese lacks..imo...ppl even colloquially say 'this kind of suckz' or 'this sort of suckz'  I would say that this kind of is more informal, and this sort of is correct

Comment: there also exist 种类：  kind genus type
category
variety
species
sort
class  and 类种 specioid (zoology, many examples at bkrs)

Answer (score 1):

- **种类** (n): '**kind**, **sort**, **kind**, **species**'

> 种 as a noun means carries the meaning of 'seed'

- **种**: things came from the same origin and divert slightly, but still belong to the same **kind** nonetheless.

For example, knife and sword are both a **kind**(种) of cold weapon because 'created to be a cold weapon' is their origin; Football and basketball are both a **kind** of a ball sport because 'created to be a ball sport' is their origin.

> 类 as a verb carries the meaning of 'to classify'

- **类**: things that's being classified into the same **sort**, **type** or **kind** based on similar origin, feature,  function or other qualities

For example, knife and sword are both a **kind/ class/ type**(类) of cold weapon ; Horse and cow are both a **kind** of cattle; Football and basketball are both a **kind** of ball sport. (we classify them based on their similarity)

Answer (score 1):

1. 这类and这种， the difference between 类and 种.
2. 类：[lèi]种类；具有某种共同属性的事物的集合。Species;A collection of things that have some sort of common property. eg 物以类聚，人以群分。Birds of a feather flock together.
3. 种：[zhǒng]种类；类别。剧种；曲种；兵种；工种。Species;Category.My character;Sort of quyi.;Type of work.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no difference between these words